# Is there a way to configure multiple IP bindings with multiple on prem IIS servers in a deployment group?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, iis-7, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a deployment group that deploys to two on premise IIS servers:  IWeb01 and IWeb02.

I have an azure release pipeline that uses a deployment group for those includes those two servers.  However, when I add the IIS Web App Manager task to my pipeline, I don't have a way to specify that IP Address 1.1.1.2 belongs to IWeb01 while 1.1.1.3 belongs to IWeb02.

Is there a way to configure this using the task?  Or do I have to resort to using appcmd to configure the bindings appropriately?

Comment: Hi. How the things going? Can the answer below give you the method to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you just need to use two **IIS web app manage** tasks and add these two bindings into them.

Here is my task configuration, you can try with that:

Add two IIS web app manage tasks first, and add the different bindings you want to configure into these different manage tasks. As the pics shown below:

[image]

[image]

After the build and release pipeline finished, you can check your IIS Manager. You will find that it's succeed.

[image]

Hope this is can help you achieve you want.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I guess that means that my deployment group which consists of 4 different web servers (each with their own IP) would then need to be split up?